# Php use data in html table

Tags: php, post, html-table

Ok, so basically I have data I have added to an html table and a save button. I want this button to submit the data in the table to a php function so that I can modify my mysql database using the data. I have the tools to modify the database, as long as I can get the data. However, I have no clue how to do this. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is very basic stuff; I recommend you work through a basic PHP/databases tutorial. All of them that I know cover this fully. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious

Comment: For a quick how-to you may also want to read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @Pekka You are likely right; I have been up all night working on a project, so I am currently really tired. I have been googling looking for a solution for a while now, and haven't found anything, so I figured I would ask here. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Addition to what @John Conde said, for every record presented in the table, you should create it's respective hidden field i.e. a    `<input type="hidden"... />`
Considering that tables have rows and columns, I will make some assumptions:

1. I will assume that the rows are equivalent to the data you have on a per record basis
2. That the columns are the fields you will update with data on a per record basis

Going on this assumption (let me assume 3 fields i.e. 3 columns and 2 records)

```
        Field 1    Field 2    Field 3
Row 1     a          b          c
Row 2     d          e          f
```

For each of these we'll create corresponding input fields in the form we'll create to contain the submit button like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <!--Row 1-->
    <input type="hidden" name="field_1[]" value="a" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_2[]" value="b" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_3[]" value="c" />
    <!--Row 2-->
    <input type="hidden" name="field_1[]" value="d" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_2[]" value="e" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_3[]" value="f" />
    <!-- more rows if they exist -->
    <input type="submit" name="my_btn" value="POST IT!" />
</form>
```

On the PHP side, you could then process the form fields, like so:

```
foreach($_POST["field_1"] as $id=>$field1_value){
    $field2_value = $_POST["field_2"][$id];
    $field3_value = $_POST["field_3"][$id];
    .......
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does help, very much, thank you. Just for clarity, the correct thing to do is update the hidden input fields when I modify the table cells using Javascript, is that correct? Or, rather, there is no way to bind the hidden input with the table cells?

Comment: They're not bound per se, you would have to reload the content (i.e. html); in other words both the form(with it's fields) and the table to reflect any new data or changes as the case may be. Consider the form's `hidden` fields as something only you the programmer has access to while the table is to tell the user what is saved there

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me solve it and get things working.

Answer (score 1):

First put your table into a < form > with some action and a method of choice (GET, POST, etc).
Like this:

```
<br>
< form id="tktk" name="tktk" method="GET" action=" < ? php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?return=Yes"><br>
  < table style="width: 98%;border:0px"><br>
    < tr><br>
      < td>etc.etc.<br>
```

Then you can submit it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['return']) && $_GET['return'] == 'Yes'){

$sql = "UPDATE [table] SET [field-a] = 1 WHERE [field-b] = '" . $id . "'";<br>
$result = sqlsrv_query($link, $sql) or die('Errant query:  '.$sql);<br>

}
```

But in general, I agree with others who recommend you step through a tutorial first to fully understand what you are coding.

Comment: Thanks. Could you by any chance edit your code to put things in line and make it more readable? Also, you are using the method post but accessing get...?

Comment: MirroredFate...I fixed the form method. Also, is there a tutorial for formatting code snippets properly on Stack Overflow? For example, I had to add an extra space in order to get things to appear within the < > carrots.

Answer (score 0):

- The data in the table either needs to be in form fields such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc so they can be submitted when the form is submitted or the data can be in <`input type="`hidden"`> fields.
- Your form needs to set the method to `POST` (although `GET` would work, too, it's not best practice_
- You will find all of your form data in the `$_POST` superglobal.